# How to make in model one side fixed?

Tags: modeling, animation

Hello everybody I have one plane and I have cubes on it. I want to observe free falling. When I animate  I want just in one side movement and the other side fixed. For example you have rectangular plane and you have cube sugars on it. And just you pour them and observe falling. Also I briefly explain in the below image. Can you help me? [image]

Comment: if you mean you want cube falling on a plane, for your ground create a plane and in the Physics panel click on Rigid Body, and choose Passive in the dropdown menu. For the cubes create a cube and in the Physics panel click on Rigid Body, and choose Active in the dropdown menu. Duplicate the cube, move them up. Now play the animation, the cubes should fall on the ground.

Comment: No , actually I want to make plane active but just in one side. When I animate it plane will move down in one side and the cubes will fall. I mean other side of plane will stay fixed. Like  below image.